# r - How can I "add" additional information to column names without altering the names themselves?

Tags: r, grouping, r-factor

I have a matrix with individual column names (the row names are not important), like this

```
TestMat<-matrix(1:25,ncol=5,nrow=5)
colnames(TestMat)<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
TestMat
```

For various reasons, but mostly because a package will later need it, I can't alter the values in the matrix and they all have to be integers.
Now I want to categorize my colum names (e.g. A, B and D into "Group 1" and C and E into "Group 2"). The idea is, that the matrix will get smaller later on, as values in the matrix are randomly diminished. As soon as a column-sum reaches zero, that column will be dropped. Along this process I want to see how the fraction/size of one group changes, compared to the other groups.
I thought the easiest way would be to just name all the corresponding columns identical:

```
TestMat2<-matrix(1:25,ncol=5,nrow=5)
colnames(TestMat2)<-c("Group1","Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2")
TestMat2
```

But this gives me error-messages later on in the analysis, as R starts numbering the identical column-names in a way of "Group1" "Group1.1" "Group2" "Group1.2" "Group2.1".

I have tried my luck with "class", "attr" and "factor" commands to my column names, but don't get anywhere. 
Is there a trick or command, I've maybe never heard of?

Comment: why not in a separate vector? that'll surely make the code much simpler?

Comment: Sounds like you might be happier creating a couple columns of `factors` and using those to treat your subsets of data.

Answer (score 1):

as per the comments why not put the grouping in another variable then something like:

```
> TestMat<-matrix(1:25,ncol=5,nrow=5)
> colnames(TestMat)<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
> F=factor(c("Group1","Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2"))
```

... do something to your matrix...

```
> summary(F[colSums(TestMat) >= 40])
Group1 Group2 
     1      2
```

Is that it (subs. 40 for 0)?

Comment: ...whoooosshh...tumbleweed..I dunno why I bother.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) package [Bioboase](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html) defines a class `ExpressionSet` that allows annotations on rows and columns of a matrix

```
library(Biobase)
exprs = matrix(1:25,ncol=5,nrow=5, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:5]))
df = data.frame(grp=c("Group1","Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2"), 
                row.names=colnames(exprs))
eset = ExpressionSet(exprs, AnnotatedDataFrame(df))
```

You can access columns in the data frame with `$`, subset with `[`, and extract with `exprs()`, e.g.,

```
> exprs(eset[, eset$grp == "Group1"])
  A  B  D
1 1  6 16
2 2  7 17
3 3  8 18
4 4  9 19
5 5 10 20
```

or

```
> eset[,colSums(exprs(eset)) > 40]$grp
[1] Group2 Group1 Group2
Levels: Group1 Group2
```

The [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html) package defines a similar class `SummarizedExperiment` when the rows are annotated with genomic ranges.

This coordinated integration of data and annotation on data is a really good thing, reducing the chance for 'clerical' errors when matrix and annotation are independent; I'm surprised so many comments suggest that you separately maintain two structures.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful comments. I haven't posted here since my original post, because I first wanted to try all promising approaches and find a final solution to my problem.

I tried the [Biobase](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html) package with its option for annotations, as well as Stephen's idea of grouping everything via a second variable.

As it turned out, as soon as the matrix diminished in size (as a part of the analysis) the external grouping failed, as column-numbers and grouping didn't match anymore and I couldn't find a way to combine the Bioconductor approach and my code.

I found a (somewhat roundabout) solution, though, if anybody cares:

I already stated, that, if I group my column-names identical for grouping, R later numbers my groups and they are thus not idential any longer.

But I then just searched for the first such-and-such neccessary letters to identify the proper group:

```
length(colnames(TestMat2)[substr(colnames(TestMat2),1,6) == "Group1"])
```

This way I can always check the fraction of one group of columns versus the others.

Thanks for your answers and help. I learned a lot and I think [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/) will come in handy in the future.

Cheers!